# Creating a javascript/react transition for expanded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, transition

I'm trying to create a transition that will expand this over half a second. I'm not sure how to go about this I tried attaching css but no use. Any suggestions?

```
const getFullMetricList = () =>
  Object.keys(comparisonChartsKeyMap)
    .map((category) => Object.values(comparisonChartsKeyMap[category]))
    .flat();
const MetricCatalog = ({ AddMetric, DeleteMetric, Metrics, width, height }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [filteredMetricList, setFilteredMetricList] = useState(
    getFullMetricList()
  );

  const handleFuzzyFilterItems = (value) => {
    let newConf = matchSorter(getFullMetricList(), value);

    setFilteredMetricList(newConf);
  };

  const handleCloseCatalog = () => {
    setExpanded(false);
    setFilteredMetricList(getFullMetricList());
  };
  if (!expanded) {
    return (
      <div
        className='metric-catalog-btn-container'
        onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
      >
        Metric Catalog
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "expand this" means? The code you posted is missing quite a bit of context. I can only glean from your post that you have a list of data that's getting vtoggled visually between an expanded & compressed state on user button click. Not nearly enough to go by in terms of offering a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className={expanded ? "expanded" : ""}
      onClick={() => setExpanded(!expanded)}
    >
      hello
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.expanded {
  width: 300px;
}
```

[complete code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-archimedes-2cd7hc?file=/src/App.js)